# while loop not working fine when inserting integers into vector

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector

While inserting elements into vector using while loop, my vector is empty. The code is not working as expected...

```
    while(n--){
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    v.push_back(a);
}
```

My vector is empty when I use this code to insert elements. However, if I use for loop it works fine. Can anyone explain why it's not working?

Comment: Can you share some more code for context? What is the value of n when you enter the loop?

Comment: It's really hard to form any conclusions without more context.  Please write a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (ideally, reading from a `std::istringstream` instead of standard input).

Comment: The problem is in some other code that you didn't show us.

Answer (score 1):

This code loops 5 times for me and produces the correct size result of 5 for the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    std::vector<int> v;
    while(n--)
    {
       int a;
       std::cin>>a;
       v.push_back(a);
    }

    std::cout << v.size() <<std::endl;

}
```

I can only assume there is an issue with your loop condition.